# Start (and display **on the remote machine**) a graphical application, via SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg

I'm certain this will have been asked elsewhere, but I can't seem to word it in a way that is picking anything up.

I have a laptop next to me that I want to test my graphical (SDL) application on, as I develop. I want to start the process by executing the program via SSH.

Is this possible and, if so, how?

Comment: belongs to superuser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already figured it out, I should have held my horses.
I entered `export DISPLAY=':0'` into my terminal (running SSH).

Comment: If you do `ssh -X` it should set the appropriate variables for you automatically.

Comment: SSH supports X11 forwarding inherently, so if you start a ssh session with -X, then you can open X11 application over your ssh connection

Comment: I don't want X forwarding, see my response to djs.

Comment: That would probably be considered a display on the local machine... local to where the program is running.  Anyway, now that we understand what you want, yes setting `DISPLAY` is the right approach.  Also note that you have to be the same user as logged into X locally, or else adjust xauth settings.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for X forwarding.

```
ssh -X user@host <program>
```

Comment: its `-X` actually (capital), `-x` will infact disable X11 forwarding, you might want to update your answer

Comment: No I'm not, X forwarding is exactly what I don't want. I want to do all of my typing on one machine, but execute (via SSH) a command that will open a program on the remote machine.

Comment: @Muu, I suggest you update your question since you didn't clearly specify you wanted to display the program remotely.